# How to show a list or array into a tree structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I pass this list from python to javascript like this:

```
 var string=["test_data/new_directory/ok.txt","test_data/reads_1.fq","test_data/test_ref.fa"];
```

I want output like this:

```
test_data
  reads_1.fq
  test_ref.fa
  new_directory
    ok.txt
```

Or also the output could be like this:

```
test_data
 reads_1.fq
 test_ref.fa

test_data/new_directory
  ok.txt
```

I used split function to get a list with each file and directory like this:

```
var string=["test_data/new_directory/ok.txt","test_data/reads_1.fq","test_data/test_ref.fa"];

                                     for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){

                                         var result = string[i].split('/');

                                          console.log(result);


                                     }
```

Output looks like this:

```
["test_data", "new_directory", "ok.txt"]
["test_data", "reads_1.fq"]
["test_data", "test_ref.fa"]
```

How can I convert into the format I showed above? Thanks

Comment: Nice one. Working on it. :)

Comment: I guess if I convert the string into JSON, it works. :)

Comment: Yes, I don't mind using JSON if it works.

Comment: Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/yMY6b/ Tried my best! :(

Comment: @PraveenKumar please see my updated question with the optional output. Do you think that kind of output can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: You should fill the tree structure in memory and then output it as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's certainly possible, but it requires recursion.

The first thing you'll want to do (as you've already figured out to do, in fact) is split on the slashes. We'll use `map` for simplicity:

```
paths = paths.map(function(path) { return path.split('/'); });
```

Now we'll want to convert this into an array of objects with `name` and `children` properties. This means we'll have to use recursion.

In this function, we'll do a first pass grouping them by their first element:

```
var items = [];
for(var i = 0, l = paths.length; i < l; i++) {
    var path = paths[i];
    var name = path[0];
    var rest = path.slice(1);
    var item = null;
    for(var j = 0, m = items.length; j < m; j++) {
        if(items[j].name === name) {
            item = items[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(item === null) {
        item = {name: name, children: []};
        items.push(item);
    }
    if(rest.length > 0) {
        item.children.push(rest);
    }
}
```

Then we can recurse on all of these (assuming the function name we chose was `structurize`):

```
for(i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    item.children = structurize(item.children);
}
```

Now we've got a nice structure. We can then stringify it, again with a recursive function. Since the directory listing is just each item name followed by the indented directory contents listing, we can write that fairly easily:

```
function stringify(items) {
    var lines = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        lines.push(item.name);
        var subLines = stringify(item.children);
        for(var j = 0, m = subLines.length; j < m; j++) {
            lines.push("  " + subLines[j]);
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Then, to actually do it:

```
console.log(stringify(structurize(paths)).join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful answer. +1. But I got this error while calling console.log at last:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @user2032220: I had a small bug; `item.children.push(rest);` should only happen if `rest.length > 0`. See my edited answer.

Comment: I am still newbie to javascript. Now, I have having problem with structuring your code. I have put the second code snippet in a function called structurize() and loop the third piece of code then I got items not defined. What does the items indicate in the for loop?

Comment: I managed code to bind in the proper structure. Finally, I get : 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Hm. May be I called recursive function in a wrong way? Can you edit your answer and put all the code together?

Comment: @user2032220: The code is all together in [the working example I linked to](http://jsfiddle.net/LJSVD/).

Comment: It's working but I have one slight problem. When I alert the result. It works fine but when I do like this: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result; 
Everything is printed in a single line.

Comment: @user2032220: That's because HTML ignores whitespace. Depending on what you want to do, you may want to build a hierarchy of elements to represent the tree or use a `pre` and `textContent`. Using `innerHTML` will create an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know. Anyway, thanks again for helping me out.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for being late to the party. I ran into a similar issue trying to break out a list of paths into a nested object. Here's a fiddle showing how I ended up doing it.

```
var list = [];
list.push("A/B/C");
list.push("A/B/D");
list.push("A/B/C");
list.push("B/D/E");
list.push("D/B/E");
list.push("A/D/C");

var data = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i< list.length; i++)
{
   buildTree(list[i].split('/'),data);    
}
debugger;

function buildTree(parts,treeNode) {
     if(parts.length === 0)
     {
          return; 
     }

     for(var i = 0 ; i < treeNode.length; i++)
     {
          if(parts[0] == treeNode[i].text)
          {
              buildTree(parts.splice(1,parts.length),treeNode[i].children);
              return;
          }
     }

     var newNode = {'text': parts[0] ,'children':[]};
     treeNode.push(newNode);
     buildTree(parts.splice(1,parts.length),newNode.children);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z07q8omt/

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to SO. Please consider editing your answer to provide more context for your answer's code. Also, please consider incorporating your url at the end of your post into text that explains why you have included it as part of the post.